# I transfer my magento 2.3 to other server and changed url base but not working

Tags: magento2.3.1, 404, base-url

I changed my Magento server but at moment not working.
Changed:
 1. web/unsecure/base_url = http://52.44.112.168/~champrob2b
 2. web/secure/base_url = http://52.44.112.168/~champrob2b
 3. Clean Cache
 4. Restart Apache

Now: 
- Stylesheet not loading
- Admin not working
- All pages going to 404

In the old server path (Sub-domain):
https://www.website.com/stoer

in the new server temporary URL (main domain):
http://52.44.112.168/~champrob2b/

Thank you for your consideration

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127333/how-to-migrate-magento-2-0-x-from-one-server-to-another

Comment: Just give the permission to your pub folder

Answer (score 1):

Please check all below steps:

1. First off all see that the database is exported to the new server.
2. Then transfer the magento root files to the new server.
3. In the root folder, change to the new database. You can do this by
   going to app/etc/env.php and changing the DB array information.
   change the host, dbname, username and password to the new one.
4. Then you change you secure and unsecure URLs in the magento DB
   core_config_data to the new IP, don't forget the "/" after your IP,
   it's required.
5. Make the web user owner of the new file ( for apache it's: sudo
   chown -R www-data /var/www/magentoroot ). Set the correct file and
   folder permissions.
6. Finally clear the cache by running bin/magento cache:clean and
   bin/magento cache:flush.

If still not load CSS etc then run below all command to regenerate all css/js in pub folder.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin\magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

I hope it will help for you.